# How to compute the gradient for a GARCH with the package rugarch in R

Tags: r, garch, gradient, quasi-likelihood

I am estimating a GARCH(1,1) with external regressors and the package `rugarch` allows me to do it easily.
However, to compute QMLE robust standard errors, I need the outer product of the gradient, and therefore, the gradient itself. The code is the following:

```
uspecSerie1 <- ugarchspec( variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",garchOrder = c(1,1), external.regressors=as.matrix(Exo)
                                           ),
                     mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(5,4), include.mean = F),
                     distribution.model = "norm")
fit.garchSerie1 <- ugarchfit(spec = uspecSerie1, data = logretSerie1)
```

The command `ugarchfit` does not compute the gradient. I tried many things, for example, with the package `NumDeriv` I tried the following:

```
grad(ugarchfit, x=fit.garchSerie1@fit$coef, spec = uspecSerie1, data = logretSerie1)
```

but it does not give results.

Can anyone help me computing the gradient for this object? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently. When it comes to robust standard errors, I am not quite sure what is implemented in the `rugarch` package but it is not QMLE.

In the vignette of the `rugarch` package the author states that the asymptotic covariance matrix is estimated via
$$
V =(-A)^{-1}B(-A)^{-1}
$$
where
$$
A = \sum_{t=1}^T\frac{\partial^2{\cal l }_t (\theta)}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^\top}
$$
and
$$
B = \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{\partial{\cal l }_t (\theta)}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial{\cal l }_t (\theta)}{\partial \theta^\top}
$$
You are able to extract these matrices form `ugarchfit`, (for instance, `fit.garchSerie1@fit$A`) so you have all your building blocks to estimate the covariance matrix.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer, it helped a lot. I simulated a time-series to check this result and I then compared it with the package `fGarch`, which has the QMLE option. I found that $A*n = hessian$, where $n$ is the number of observations. Computing
`````
A<-fit.garchSerie1@fit$A*n
B<-fit.garchSerie1@fit$B*n
sqrt(diag(solve(A)%*%B%*%solve(A)))
````
it gives the robust SE. For me, by reading the formula, it seems like the QMLE SE, and it gives similar (not equal) results as the `fGarch` packages. PD: the non-robust EE are quite different among the two packages.

Comment: Try the following. Set `dist = "norm"` and then compute the estimate. This should correspond to QMLE.

Comment: If I don´t find a way to compute the gradient by myself (the $n x k$ matrix), I thinks I will be forced to use this SE. But my quest is just begining haha

Comment: In which command?

Comment: Since QMLE is maximizing the gaussian likelihood, you could set `distribution.model = "norm"` in `ugarchspec` then estimate the model and compute the "sandwich" estimate. The result should be nearly the same as in `fgarch`.